# Select all Nodes Innertext any depth

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, nodes, nodelist

I have a problem that I'm thinking about for hours now. Maybe I just think the wrong way ... Whatever:

I have multiple XML Documents that I search for (recursive file search) and load as "XmlDocument"

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(New StreamReader(File.Open(strFilePathAndName, FileMode.Open), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-15")))
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
```

Then I have to search in this document for every child note, but not it's "parent" 
A bit hard to explain ... Well as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<rootnode>
    <node1>Users</node1>            '<- Get "Users" from that
    <node2>xxxxxx</node2>           '<- Get "xxxxxxx" from that
    <node3>                         '<- Don't get that
        <node4>                     '<- Don't get that
            <nodeX>xxxxxx</nodeX>   '<- Get xxxxx that
            <node5>                 '<- Don't get that
                <bla>335</bla>      '<- Get 335 fromthat
                <bla2>3353</bla2>   '<- Get 3353 from that
            </node5>
        <node4>     
</rootnode>
```

Original is a bit larger...

I tried saving them in a NodeList:

```
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::*")
```

And then saving all found items to a string, seperated by ";" :

```
For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList
        ergstring = ergstring & """" & node.InnerText & """" & ";"
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::*[not(*)]")` to select all elements not having a child element.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Sometimes the answer is so simple ^^